# new line is not created when trying to update a text in a text file

Tags: php

Im trying to update a text file using the code below:

```
$filename = "flat-file-data.txt"; // File which holds all data
$rowToUpdate = $_REQUEST['number']; // This is line need to be updated
$newString = $_REQUEST['line'].'\r\n'; // This is what you want to replace it with

$arrFp = file( $filename ); // Open the data file as an array
// Replace the current element in array which needs to be updated with new string
$arrFp[$rowToUpdate-1] = $newString; 
$numLines = count( $arrFp ); // Count the elements in the array

$fp = fopen( $filename, "w" ); // Open the file for writing
for($i=0; $i < $numLines; $i++)
{
    fwrite($fp, $arrFp[$i]);
}
fclose( $fp ); // Close the file
```

as you can see from the above codes, it will update the line 1 with the data from $newString and it should be able to create a new line after each line with this '\r\n'.

Unfortunately, it doesnt create a new line, it just goes along with the same line or in the current line like for example 'this is the firstline\r\nthis is the second line'. Is there any accurate way that I could make it in a new line like

```
this is the firstline
this is the secondline
```

and so on and so forth?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `\r\n` in double quotes:

```
$newString = $_REQUEST['line']."\r\n";
```